# How does a scalar potential $V$ that follows $\rho$ momentarily lead to infinite propagation velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, gauge-theory, causality, faster-than-light

$$\nabla^2V(\mathbf r,t)=-\frac{\rho(\mathbf r,t)}{\epsilon_0}\implies V(\mathbf r,t)=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf r',t)}R\mathrm d\tau'$$

I am trying to  understand how this equation $\implies\infty$ propagation velocity. During lecture it was a heavy proof that I didn't understand, so maybe someone could explain the basic idea how to interprete this equation.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the equation as-written - ordinarily, I would expect to see
$$V(\mathbf r, t) = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf r',t)}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}\mathrm d^3 r'$$
In any case, the reason for this is straightforward.  If $\rho(\mathbf r',t)$ suddenly changes at $t=0$, then $V(\mathbf r,t)$ changes suddenly at $t=0$. For example, imagine two point charges sitting on top of each other at the origin, so the charge density vanishes everywhere.  Suddenly at time $t=0$ the two charges move an infinitesimal distance $\epsilon$ apart, creating a dipole with moment $\mathbf p = q\epsilon \hat z$.  If you compute $ V(\mathbf r, t)$ for any $t>0$, you will clearly obtain the dipole potential
$$V(\mathbf r,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left( \frac{q}{|\mathbf r - \epsilon \hat z/2|} - \frac{q}{|\mathbf r+\epsilon \hat z/2|}\right)\simeq \frac{\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf p}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}$$

In this sense, the time variable is just a spectator; it doesn't play an active role in the integral. Any change that occurs in $\rho$ is immediately reflected in a change in $V$ *at every point in space*.

On the other hand, if we utilize the Lorenz gauge then we find that

$$V(\mathbf r,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int \frac{\rho(\mathbf r', t')}{|\mathbf r- \mathbf r'|} \mathrm d^3r' \qquad t' \equiv t - |\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|/c$$

This is a different story because the $\rho$ inside the integral is evaluated at $t'$ rather than at $t$.  The contribution to $V$ from a point $\mathbf r'$ depends on the charge density at $\mathbf r'$ *at a time $\delta t =|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|/c$ in the past*. Changing the charge density at a point $\mathbf r'$ does not change the potential at some point $\mathbf r$ until the time $|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'|/c$ has elapsed, which means that changes in $V$ propagate at $c$.

---

As pointed out by Michael Seifert in the comments, there is no causality violation in the Coulomb gauge even though changes in $V$ apparently propagate infinitely quickly. The reason for this is that neither $V$ nor the vector potential $\mathbf A$ are physically observable; only the electric and magnetic fields are, and $\mathbf E$ depends on both $V$ and $\mathbf A$ as
$$\mathbf E = -\nabla V - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbf A$$
It is an excellent exercise to show that the apparently acausal propagation of changes in $\nabla V$ is exactly canceled out by a corresponding term in $\partial \mathbf A/\partial t$, with the result being that changes in $\mathbf E$ propagate at $c$.

Of course, this is also clear because causality is manifestly preserved in the Lorenz gauge, and $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ are invariant under gauge transformation.

Comment: It's worth noting that a sudden instantaneous change in $V$ does not violate causality, since $V$ is not directly observable.  What's observable is $\vec{E}$, which also depends on the vector potential $\vec{A}$ when you're talking about dynamical fields.  This issue arises if you're foolish enough to try to do electrodynamics in Coulomb gauge;  it turns out that $\vec{E}$ does propagate causally (of course), even though $V$ and $\vec{A}$ appear to be acausal.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Excellent point, thank you. I've added a note to the end of my answer.